# I Can't write in input element

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I can't write in input inside the expansion-panel, the focus is removed once I click on the input.

here is it my code!

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of listSousCategorie">
          <mat-expansion-panel  class="childPanel" [expanded]="true" hideToggle disabled style=" background:#ecfaff;">
            <div class="childPanel_body2 mat-badge-large" fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center"  >
              <div style="padding-left:1em" fxFlex="grow" >{{i.libelle}}</div>
              <mat-form-field style="width:50px" appearance="standard" [formGroup]="form">
                <mat-label>Note</mat-label>
                <input  type="text" matInput  formControlName="Note" " >
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: use `OnPush` change detection strategy and use a `trackBy` function for your `ngFor` loop

Comment: Probably because your changing listSousCategorie with the input?

Comment: @MikeOne yes ! because I what i want is whenever I click on expansion panel, it shows the cards of lisSousCategorie with the input

Comment: @PoulKruijt Can u please explain more how can I do that !

Comment: If you indeed change listSousCategorie when the input changes - then Angular will detect that and rebuild the list (it re-triggers the ngFor). using trackBy might help - but it is still a bit risky to do this.

Comment: Might also want to change `formControlName="Note" "` to `formControlName="Note"`.

Comment: @Dudi yes i fix it,  its not the error